# Merge all HashMap<String,List<Article>> values into a List<Article>

Tags: java, list, hashmap

I've here a `Map<String, List<Article>> selections` and I would like to merge all of its values inside a single `List<Article>`.

I tried this:

```
for (Iterator i = selections.keySet().iterator() ; i.hasNext() ; ){
    String cle = (String)i.next();
    select = selections.get(cle);
}
```

However, I end up having only the latest entry. How can I get them all in a single `List`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a **new** `List` *before* iterating and then iterate over `Map#values()` and then add every `List` to the new `List` via its [`addAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)) method.

```
List<Article> selectedArticles = new ArrayList<>();

for (List<Article> selection : selections.values()) {
    selectedArticles.addAll(selection);
}

// Now use selectedArticles.
```

#### See also:

- [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) - [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html) - [Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html)

Comment: You should only run it when you want to display all selected articles.

Comment: Ok @BalusC I did it and it work nice..But I still have one problem..if I chose a category and then chose another one and return to the previous one I have duplicated articles in the list.I try to use `Set` but the problem persist :\

Comment: You should only run it when you want to display all selected values. Not when you change the selection.

Comment: I have done this but still have the same problem..It seams that their are duplicated value in selections (the hashMap which contains selected items)..how can I be sure that their are no duplicated items?I try different method to elimate duplicated article but in vain..can someone help me please?